# php mysqli class

Tags: php, class, methods, mysqli

My basic problem is I am having trouble accessing a class from within another class. Here is what I have set up so far:

My DB class:

```
class db {

    public static $mysqli;
    public function __construct(){}

    static function con(){
        if(!self::$mysqli){
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        }
        return self::$mysqli;
    }
}
```

This works all fine and dandy when I just call it from a function like such:

```
function defineSettings(){
  if ($query = db::con()->prepare(...my query...)) {    
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($1, $2, $3);
    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();
  }

  db::con()->close();

}
```

However, I am having trouble accessing this db->con() method from within another class' method. I have tried extending it to a new class, but maybe I am doing it wrong. An example of how to use this from a new class would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: make sure you define `db::con()` as `public static function` and `public class db`

Comment: Once doing that, how to I call this from a method from within another class?

Comment: as long as the code's are in the same file (or the file with `class db` is included in the other file) then it should just work.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC      when stating public class db

Comment: ahh, well remove the `public` from `public class db`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understood your question, but the class below should show how you can get the db object from the `Db` class, and then use it in another function

```
class Example2 {
    private $db;

    public function test() {
        if (!$this->db) {
            $this->db = db::con();
        }
        //Do your stuff
    }

    public function test2() {
        $this->db->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just get an error: mysqli::close() [mysqli.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in ...